# Selects on table behaving weirdly

Tags: sql-server, database, hibernate

We have a table called T_USER containing columns that you would expect (primary key with identity, foreign keys and basic columns).

We have a Java EE Web application working with this database using hibernate.

Problem is on freshly initialized table T_USER with initial (preconstructed) data hibernate transaction working with the table gets stuck (is blocked and runs out) while working with different database with the same table version(structure) and filled with data from a customer, transaction is working fine (same Java EE web application build).

**Even more weird** is that deleting rows in bulks (e.g. 100 rows at a time) from the customer database doesn't break the transaction but deleting all but 3 rows does break it.

Does anybody have any idea what may caue this issue?

EDIT:
Although I think it's quite irrelevant, I enclose the stack trace of the error when transaction fails (The reason I find it irrelevant is the weird different behaviour with different data and different method of deleting rows):

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:203)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:364)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
at our.company.core.changeRequest.dao.CrDAO$$$view415.closePackageError(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:411)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
at our.company.core.changeRequest.dao.CrDAO$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.closePackageError(Unknown Source)
at our.company.core.changeRequest.dao.ChangeRequestDAO.realizeChangeRequestPackage(ChangeRequestDAO.java:184)
at our.company.core.changeRequest.dao.ChangeRequestDAO.createChangeRequest(ChangeRequestDAO.java:111)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:388)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:146)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:81)
at our.company.core.changeRequest.dao.ChangeRequestDAO$$$view298.createChangeRequest(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:411)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:134)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:68)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:106)
at our.company.core.changeRequest.dao.ChangeRequestDAO$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.createChangeRequest(Unknown Source)
at our.company.body.identity.ChangePasswordBean.changeUserPasswordForConnector(ChangePasswordBean.java:464)
at our.company.body.identity.ChangePasswordBean.save(ChangePasswordBean.java:414)
at our.company.main.MainPageBeanView.save(MainPageBeanView.java:1517)
at our.company.main.MainPageBeanView.saveAndExit(MainPageBeanView.java:1557)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:226)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:209)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:221)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:147)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler.handleResult(HttpRewriteResultHandler.java:42)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.rewrite(RewriteFilter.java:297)
at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:198)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at our.company.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:339)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1514)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a0a1670:-f843fd9:5d9db76e:529 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:114)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:256)
    ... 136 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a0a1670:-f843fd9:5d9db76e:529 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95)
    ... 138 moreCaused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TypedQueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.getResultList(TypedQueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.java:58)
at our.company.core.changeRequest.dao.CrDAO.closePackageError(CrDAO.java:345)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:185)
... 207 moreCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:109)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1934)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:370)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1339)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
... 234 moreCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:146)
at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
... 255 moreCaused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:425)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
... 259 moreCaused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000459: Transaction is not active: tx=Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0a0a1670:-f843fd9:5d9db76e:529 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:409)
... 261 more
```

Comment: Maybe the DB user doesn't have full access to T_USER table?

Comment: When you encounter errors and are asking others for help you need to provide the error messages. Otherwise everybody is left guessing what the issue might be.